# Highcharts dynamic set category update the chart but shows only points but not lines

Tags: php, jquery, yii, highcharts

I have **Highchart LINE type graph** which show line graph correctly.I have button to change the data dynamically.i.e. First chart renders 7 days data.On click of 14 days chart renders data correctly but the when i use.

```
function requestData(response,point){
...data fetching code......
var series = chart.series[0];
chart.series[1].setData(eval(oneArray),false,true);
chart.series[0].setData(eval(twoArray),false,true);
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(json array, true,true);}
```

if i remove the `chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(json array, true,true);` then it show the lines with correct data but x-axis is only numbers,I have to set x-axis with days name.The json array show all correct.
Here is my chart code.

```
                   var chart;
                   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                   chart: {
                       renderTo: "progresschart",
                       type: "line",
                       events: {
                           load: requestData   
                       }
                   },
                   credits: {
                           enabled: false
                       },
                   title: {
                       text: "Calories Burned Vs Calorie Consumed"
                   },
                    xAxis: {

                           categories: [],
                           },

                   yAxis: {
                       title: {
                           text: "Calories"
                       },
                   },
                   series: [{
                       name: "Consumed",
                        data:[] 
                   },{
                       name: "Burned",
                        data:[] 
                   }],
                   exporting: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
              });
        });
```

First the category array is:

```
["Thu,28th", "Fri,29th", "Sat,30th", "Sun,1st", "Mon,2nd", "Tue,3rd", "Wed,4th"]
```

categories array to be set is:

```
["Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"]
```

Series[1]:

```
[403.91604166667, 0, 0, 156.421875, 190.48708333333, 121.66145833333, 52.140625, 104.28125, 440.41447916667, 472.04645833334, 0, 178.3209375, 191.18229166666, 139.04166666667]
```

Series[2]:

```
[100, 112, 0, 0, 360, 330, 141, 150, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: It would be very good idea to attach example data, otherwise it's hard to say what may go wrong. For both series and categories.

Comment: @PawełFus question updated..

Comment: Please attach series.

Comment: I've always had to setCategories() with no parameters to clear it, then it will redraw correctly on a second call with the parameters I need

Comment: @SebastianBochan Series is attached for dynamic data

Comment: Tried to reproduce issue on jsFiddle. Data and categories seems proper. Am I missing something in that example: http://jsfiddle.net/24dXX/ ? Only one thing comes to my mind - do you have 3.0.7 version of Highcharts? Maybe one of older version has some bug.

Comment: @PawełFus You save my day man.This small things we developers always forgot to do.Am working on old version.Thats the main problem.Thanks a ton for your support and definately if my client likes it i will support Highcharts developers team. Cheers!! Post this as answer so that others can also get help.

Comment: Sure, done. Great to hear that it's solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably bug in old version of Highcharts, updating to 3.0.7+ should resolve that issue.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/24dXX/

Code:

```
    var arr = ["Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
        oneArray = "[403.91604166667, 0, 0, 156.421875, 190.48708333333, 121.66145833333, 52.140625, 104.28125, 440.41447916667, 472.04645833334, 0, 178.3209375, 191.18229166666, 139.04166666667]",
        twoArray = "[100, 112, 0, 0, 360, 330, 141, 150, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]";

    chart.series[1].setData(eval(oneArray), false, true);
    chart.series[0].setData(eval(twoArray), false, true);
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(arr, true, true);
```